# How do I make a jquery id selection equal to this inside a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

Why do I get an error when I try and make `$("#select-province")` `that.value`?

```
function updateCities(that){
   console.log(that.value);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
      updateCities($("#select-province"));
});
```

Comment: Please specify the error you got

Comment: $("#select-province") will return you jQuery object where it should be read like $(that).val()

Comment: @Nps actually I think it would be `that.val()` since `that` would be a jQuery object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert jquery object to javascript object.use:

```
function updateCities(that){
  console.log(that.value);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  updateCities($("#select-province")[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Choose 1, but not both:

- Pass a DOM object, and not a jQuery object

  ```
  function updateCities(that){
      console.log(that.value);
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
      updateCities(document.getElementById('select-province'));
  });
  ```
- Because you're passing a jQuery object, use the library's function to properly retrieve the value:

  ```
  function updateCities($that){
      console.log($that.val());  // or $that.prop('value')
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
      updateCities($("#select-province"));
  });
  ```

  *Notice that I changed the name of `that` to `$that` to reflect it being a jQuery object.*

Answer (score 0):

When using jQuery, than use jQuery whereever you can.

```
function updateCities(that){
  console.log($(that).val());
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  updateCities($("#select-province"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use jquery $(that).val() its working fine.

```
function updateCities(that){
  console.log($(that).val());
}

$(document).ready(function(){
      updateCities($("#select-province"));
});
```

see fiddle link  http://jsfiddle.net/5AX6p/1/